# pageshow not working in apache cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

Hello I am trying to implement the "pageshow" because I need to block the return if the page button that will take is the login.Porém the method "pageshow" is not called , so I can not apply logic:

```
    // and then run "window.location.reload()" in the JavaScript Console.
    (function () {
        "use strict";
        var pageHistoryCount = 0;
        var goingBack = false;

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            document.addEventListener('pause', onPause.bind(this), false);
            document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);
            document.addEventListener('backbutton', backButtonHandler, false);
            $(document).bind("pageshow", function (e, data) {
                console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
                if (goingBack) {
                    goingBack = false;
                } else {
                    pageHistoryCount++;
                    console.log("HERE");
                }
            });
            // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
        };        
        function onPause() {
        };
        function onResume() {
        };
        function exitApp() {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        };
        function backButtonHandler(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(pageHistoryCount);
            if (pageHistoryCount > 0) pageHistoryCount--;
            if (pageHistoryCount == 0) {

            } else {
                goingBack = true;
                console.log("Going back to page #" + pageHistoryCount);
                window.history.back();
            }

            //Here implement the back button handler
        };      
    })();
```

Comment: What platform are you testing with?

Comment: Also, does this repro on a device or are you only seeing this in Ripple?

Comment: as far as I know, pageshow is an old jquery mobile event, so as you didn't add a jquery mobile tag in your question, that's probably the issue

Comment: hello I'm testing the device , what other choice do I do to identify when viewing a page?thanks a lot

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do you're looking to redirect to a login page?  Typically that is accomplished using a page load event or deviceready if you have separate pages.  If you are using a framework like Angluar instead and won't actually be transitioning pages the framework usually has a way to track when a new page has been loaded into the DOM.

Comment: First thank you for helping me. Yes I'm trying not to go back to the login screen, but put " document.referrer " the method backButtonHandler, and returns me empty.

Comment: Can you provide some additional info on where you are seeing this?  Android? Windows? iOS? Device?  Simulator? Ripple?  All of the above?  Also, what version of Cordova?